# Simple SBT Module in Play Project Causes Play to Crash for Unknown reason - play 2.1

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

https://github.com/jasongoodwin/play21-multimodule-demo has the code.
I've recreated this problem on 3 different projects. I don't know what's up.
once you put the aggregate and dependsOn in the build.scala file the project throws an error when trying to start play.

> [info] Loading global plugins from /Users/jgoodwin/.sbt/plugins [info]
>   Loading project definition from
>   /Users/jgoodwin/Development/src/ninjakeyboard/test/tmp/play21-multimodule-demo/project
>   [error] java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError [error] Use 'last' for
>   the full log. Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or
>   (i)gnore? q

Build file

> import sbt._ import Keys._ import play.Project._
>
> object ApplicationBuild extends Build {
>
> val appName         = "multimodule-demo"   val appVersion      =
>   "1.0-SNAPSHOT"   //val scalaVersion    = "2.10.0"
>
> val appDependencies = Seq(
>       // Add your project dependencies here,
>       jdbc,
>       anorm   )
>
> val buildSettings = (
>         scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
>       )
>
> val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, path =
>   file("web")).settings(
>       // Add your own project settings here   ).aggregate(testmodule).dependsOn(testmodule)
>
> val testmodule = Project(
>       "testmodule",
>       file("testmodlue"),
>       settings = buildSettings   )
>
> }

Comment: Probably going to need more information since there's too many open variables. It could come down to repos not being available, a conflict between target and runtime SBT versions. Can you get the full log during load?

Comment: The github repository with the application is there - you can check it out and try. Way too many variables for me to provide anything more useful than the actual code itself.

Comment: hmmmm...at this point i might suggest copying an existing module and using it as a "template". then doing a DIFF to see if you missed anything. it's a lot of work to sift through the whole repo

Comment: I've recreated the problem 3 times. This is just a stock new project with a g8 template used for the submodule. I followed the play documentation and this is the result. Can't find anyone who has done this on 2.1 yet.

Comment: Your project structure looks completely different compared to a regular Play project.. I have no experience with SBT, just the play commands, perhaps the structure is causing crashes.

Comment: As per documentation, this is not an abnormal project structure at all. With an sbt oriented approach, play module is just that - a module that depends on other modules. see here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/SBTSubProjects

Same structure.
[...]
  val appDependencies = Seq(
    //if it's a java project add javaCore, javaJdbc, jdbc etc.
  )
  
  val mySubProject = Project("my-library", file("myLibrary"))

  val main = play.Project(
    appName, appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("myProject")
  ).dependsOn(mySubProject)

[...]

Comment: @JasonG did you find a solution to your problem? I'm trying to set-up a similar structure.

Comment: I haven't been using play - it's pretty heavy weight. I think scalatra is pretty good. Sorry I can't be of more help!

Answer (score 3):

I noticed in your github build.scala that testmodule is declared (and initialized) after the main module, thus the null exception during project loading.
I made the same mistake and putting the modules in the right order made it work.
I just started playing with Play2 and Scala, but I believe the use of lazy val could also help.

Comment: Thanks - I'll check it out and try. It's a good piece of info to have on stack.

Comment: I attest to run into the same java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError in non-play sbt project. Solved it by placing dependent task first (it was in the wrong order initially, I thought it doesn't matter).

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a fresh project:

1. Run command: `play new MyApp`
2. Run `play clean eclipse`
3. Make dir `modules` (inside MyApp)
4. Run command `play new MyModule`
5. Run command `play clean eclipse`
6. Rename controller to MyModuleCon, and change the routes file
7. Run command `play clean publish-local`
8. Add to your MyApp Build.scala the dependency: `"mymodule" % "mymodule_2.10" % "1.0-SNAPSHOT"`
9. Rename main route to app.routes (because modules has also routes, although it can be deleted!)
10. On the main project run: `play dependencies eclipse`

Voila, you have your submodule, see my github: https://github.com/adis-me/PlayModuleExample

Just run `play run` and visit main project at: `http://localhost:9000` and then visit the submodule: `http://localhost:9000/module`.

This should do the trick, for you, I think!

**EDIT: 2013-03-27**

Changing the above configuration to a real sub project setup, follow these steps:

1. Run on MyApp: `play clean`
2. Change MyApp's Build.scala file:

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

```
  val appName         = "MyAppp"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean
  )

  val subproject = play.Project(
    "sub-project", appVersion, appDependencies, path = file("modules/MyModule")
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    // Add your own project settings here      
  ).dependsOn(subproject).aggregate(subproject)

}
```

1. Run commands: `play clean eclipse`
2. Run commands: `play run`

That's it, you can no visit the same urls as above mentioned.
It can be that your idea does not recognize the classes from your subproject, just reference the MyModule project as referenced library for the main project, and you are good to go.

Good luck!

Comment: I'll try this out. Note though that you still don't have the play project in another folder like the documentation: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/SBTSubProjects
See first code example there.

Comment: Not sure if it's an intellij only issue as I'm using it with an ultimate license but I don't imagine so.

Comment: Yeah, you can take this example (with two Play projects) and make it work and then try to convert or add a 'regular' SBT project. I only have worked with Play projects. Good luck and please inform us with your progress.